# UIBubbleTableView doesn't render in IOS 64-bit simulator

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, 32bit-64bit, uibubbletableview

I'm running out of ideas and hoping someone in the community might give me some pointers.  I'm currently using `UIBubbleTableView` (http://alexbarinov.github.io/UIBubbleTableView/) to integrate in-app chat into my project.  Everything works/renders fine when I use iOS non-64-bit simulators.  Once I use the iOS 64-bit simulator, the UIBubbleTable doesn't render.  Here's what I know:

**1.** It's not a problem with the `datasource`. The data loads fine.  `numberOfRowsInSection`, `numberOfSectionsInTableView`, `cellForRowAtIndexPath` all return expected non-null results.

**2.** The example `UIBubbleTableView` project looks like it works fine with the 64-bit simulator.

**3.** I created a test ViewController in my own project and copy and pasted ViewController.m/h/xib straight from the example project to my project and the bubbletable doesn't show.

I'm now wondering if it's a 64-bit caching or configuration issue. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm having this problem as well, were you able to solve it?

Comment: Did you set the storyboard correctly? You should post the code for the VC to let us see what's wrong

Answer (score 5):

replace

```
(float)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

for

```
(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

in `UIBubbleTableView.m`

Comment: It would be nice if you mark rafaelrcm 's answer as answered.

Answer (score 1):

I make it to work by changing the the project "Build Settings" and under "Architectures" change it to match what the UIBubbleTableView use which is  "$(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT)". But I do want to know why if it is set to 64bit, the cell don't render. Hope will hear someone actually able to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The reason will be down to using the wrong variable types. Especially in UITableView-related functions don't use float or int, use CGFloat and NSInteger as these are double the size in the 64-bit architecture so appear to be causing some problems!

Answer (score 0):

Check the discussion here: [https://github.com/AlexBarinov/UIBubbleTableView/issues/69](http://github%20-%20UIBubbleTableView) For those who are new, rafaelcrm's answer is the correct one.